# Segmented style picker alignment in NavigationBarItems

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigationbar

I'm now working on putting segmented style picker inside NavigationBarItems.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let modes = ["temperature", "distance"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                ...
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems (leading:
                                    Picker ("Select mode:", selection: $currentMode) {
                                        ForEach (0..<mods.count) {
                                            Text(self.mods[$0])
                                        }
                                    }
                                    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

If I use `leading:` the picker is shown on the left, if I use `trailing:` then the picker is shown on the right. How can I put it in the **centre**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.toolbar` instead, like

```
ZStack {
    Text("Demo")
}
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
        Picker ("Select mode:", selection: $currentMode) {
            ForEach (0..<modes.count) {
                Text(self.modes[$0])
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
    }
}
```

[image]